# Storing cross site cookies on Safari using Heroku + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cookies, safari

I'm not getting any errors or problems storing cookies on chrome or firefox, but with the default cookie settings on Safari...i seem to get quite a bit of problem with getting cookies to store properly.

I'm doing cross site (rendering an iframe from another domain) so i'm not sure if there is something special i should be doing for this on Safari.

http://prntscr.com/e1yt22
This setting will always make my website work properly and store cookies.

http://prntscr.com/e1ytfc
This setting will however not.

EDIT 1: Someone said to do this

> The solution is to access the API/service from a sub-domain, e.g.
>   “api.somedomain.com”. This should cause Safari to hold onto the cookie
>   so it can be re-used for the CORS requests.

Will the workaround with subdomain work if both domains are different?
Will I get trouble with cookies if I do this on safari, which doesn't allow 3rd party cookies by default?

example: `<iframe src="xyz.example.com"></iframe>` inside xyz.com website ?

Or does it have to be like this: 
`<iframe src="xyz.example.com"></iframe>` inside example.com website?